# Not sure how to assign $$ the value of a token

Tags: c, parsing, yacc

I am trying to give $$ the value of a token.

Eg: Relevant Code

```
%token VOID

... Yacc Code...

variableType : VOID {}; /*How to I assign variableType to the token VOID.*/
```

I was thinking it would be $$=$1, but this is incorrect since $1 looks for the value, but this is a token. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want `$$ = VOID;`.

In bison/yacc, tokens are smallish ints, and they are given names with an `enum` declaration inserted bith into the generated parser and the generated header file, which is how the scanner can use it to return a token.

If you intend for the semantic value  of the token `void` to be the token's enum value `VOID`, it woyld probably be cleaner to that as  the semantic value in the lexer, using a lexer action like `yylval = VOID; return yylval;` or even `return (yylval = VOID);`. Then you could use `$1` in the parser action.

However, I'm not saying that using token enums to identify types is a good idea.

Comment: @antti: that is precisely an example of why i think it unlikely that using an integer value such as 273 (which is a plausible value for s bison token) seems wierd. A PHP type hint aiui is one of a small collection of type keywords, `void`, or an arbitrary identifier which names a class. In the last case, the semantic value should allow an action to recover the actual identifier; for keywords it might well be an enum, but it would be more common to number from 0 or 1. So you might expect a pointer to a string or a symtab with some distinguished values. But a nedium-sized int???

Comment: Ah indeed, I somehow remembered that PHP used to have `(void)` cast before (of course it didn't); in JavaScript, `void` is an operator, but yeah perhaps there too it would make sense to have these under a single keyword token type.